# Setting up Plesk as proxy server for my browser

Tags: server, plesk, proxy-server, static-ip-address

I have tried to find info on this, but can't seem to find what I am actually looking for.

I have a server running plesk. What I would like to do is set it up so that I can run my browser through that and have a static IP address. Is this possible and if so, any pointers on how to set this up?

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is a few years old, but in case someone stumbles upon it. It's quite easy now with Onyx and Docker.

1. Create a new Docker instance with [robhaswell/squid-authenticated](https://hub.docker.com/r/robhaswell/squid-authenticated/).
2. Configure as follows:

[image: squid-authenticated Docker Settings]

Comment: I've found other squid implementations, however I'm interested into configure Squid to run on only one IP (my server have multiple IP's). IS there any way to configure that?
Also, I'm an absolute ignorant on docker... how do I get access to the docker "image"? because I'd like to tweak the squid.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to install proxy server like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) or [tinyproxy](https://banu.com/tinyproxy/) or [3proxy](http://www.3proxy.ru/?l=EN)

Also as a more simpler but with more limitations you can create a domain and use one of PHP proxies like [this one](https://github.com/joshdick/miniproxy) or [this one](https://code.google.com/p/php-proxy/)

Don't forget about authentication.